# Finding Optimal Transfer Paths in a Network with Capacity Restrictions

Tags: c++, algorithm

The classic definition of maximum flow in a network is not used in this problem statement.

A network is given, consisting of **n** pumping stations, some of which are connected by pipes. The capacity of each pipe is specified.

For each pair of stations with numbers **u** and **v**, we need to find an optimal set of pipes that allows us to transfer the largest volume of gas from station **u** to station **v**. The pipes must form a simple path.

The volume of gas transferred between stations **u**  and **v**  is directly proportional to the smallest capacity of the pipes on the simple path from station **u**  to station **v**. If there is no path between the vertices, output 0. If there are no restrictions on the capacity, output 1,000,000,009.

**Input format:**
The first line contains a single integer **n** **(1 <= n <= 500)** - the number of pumping stations in the network.

Next, the adjacency matrix of the network is given: **n** lines of **n** numbers** g_{i j} (-1 <= g_{i, j}<=10^9)**. If there are no pipes between the i-th and j-th stations, then **g_{i, j}=0**. If there are no restrictions on capacity, then **g_{i, j}=-1**.

It is guaranteed that all elements on the main diagonal of the **g** matrix are zero.

**Output format:**
Output the answer to the problem in the form of a matrix **ans_{u,v}**, where **ans_{u,v}** is equal to the smallest capacity of the pipe on the optimal path from station u to station v.

If **u = v** or there is a path without capacity restrictions, then we will consider **ans_{u,v}=1,000,000,009**. If there is no path from vertex **u** to vertex **v**, output 0.

*Example Input:*

```
3
0 145 43
-1 0 -1
20 -1 0
```

*Example Output:*

```
1000000009 145 145
1000000009 1000000009 1000000009
1000000009 1000000009 1000000009
```

*Example Input:*

```
2
0 -1
-1 0
```

*Example Output:*

```
1000000009 1000000009
1000000009 1000000009
```

*Example Input:*

```
3
0 11 11
-1 0 23
32 232 0
```

*Example Output:*

```
1000000009 11 11
1000000009 1000000009 23
232 232 1000000009
```

I tried to use the floyd-warshell algorithm, but I get the wrong answer. Maybe we should use a different algorithm here?
Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int INF = 1e9 + 9;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> inp(n, vector<int>(n));
    vector<vector<int>> res(n, vector<int>(n, INF));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> inp[i][j];
            if (i == j || inp[i][j] == -1) {
                res[i][j] = INF;
            }
            else if (inp[i][j] > 0) {
                res[i][j] = inp[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
            if (u != v && inp[u][v] == 0) {
                for (int k = u + 1; k < v; k++) {
                    res[u][v] = min(res[u][v], max(res[u][k], res[k][v]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto& x : res) {
        for (int i : x) {
            if (i == INF) {
                cout << 1000000009 << " ";
            }
            else {
                cout << i << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any hints or an implementation of the correct algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the [Floyd-Warshell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm that follows the linked pseudo-code but is adapted to find the maximum flow instead of the minimum weight. It also includes a simple `Matrix` class to simplify the indexing. It correctly processes all of the examples.

```cpp
template<class T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(size_t nrows, size_t ncols)
        : nrows_(nrows)
        , ncols_(ncols)
        , data_(nrows * ncols) {
    }

    auto nrows() const {
        return nrows_;
    }

    auto ncols() const {
        return ncols_;
    }

    const auto& operator[](size_t i, size_t j) const {
        return data_[i * ncols_ + j];
    }

    auto& operator[](size_t i, size_t j) {
        return data_[i * ncols_ + j];
    }

private:
    size_t nrows_, ncols_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < matrix.nrows(); ++i) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < matrix.ncols(); ++j)
            os << matrix[i, j] << " ";
        os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const int MaxFlow = 1'000'000'009;

    std::string line;
    std::getline(cin, line);

    auto n = core::str::lexical_cast<int>(line);
    Matrix<int> graph(n, n);
    size_t rdx{};
    while (std::getline(cin, line)) {
        auto fields = core::str::split(line, " ");
        if (fields.size() != n)
            throw core::runtime_error("expected {} fields, but found {}", n, fields.size());

        for (auto i = 0; i < fields.size(); ++i)
            graph[rdx, i] = core::str::lexical_cast<int>(fields[i]);
        ++rdx;
    }

    cout << "input: " << endl;
    cout << graph << endl;

    for (auto i = 0; i < graph.nrows(); ++i) {
        graph[i, i] = MaxFlow;
        for (auto j = 0; j < graph.ncols(); ++j)
            if (graph[i, j] < 0)
                graph[i, j] = MaxFlow;
    }

    cout << "flows: " << endl;
    cout << graph << endl;

    for (auto k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (auto j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                if (graph[i, j] < std::min(graph[i, k], graph[k, j]))
                    graph[i, j] = std::min(graph[i, k], graph[k, j]);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "best: " << endl;
    cout << graph << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimal path between u and v is part of the maximum weight spanning tree.  A tree only contains one path between any two vertices, so if you find a maximum weight spanning tree, you will find an optimal path for every pair.

To find the maximum path capacities all at once, I recommend using [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) to find a maximum capacity spanning tree.

In the process of finding that tree, whenever you create the union of two sets, the current edge capacity is the capacity to fill in for the connections between all the vertices in one of the sets, and all the vertices in the other one.